# CountUp.js: useEasing = false doesn't count up with exact time

Tags: javascript

I want to use CountUp.js for number counting as it provides a nice animation. However, I want to allow the user to set the speed of the counter. However, I found that the timer is a bit wrong.

I am following the example provided in https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/ and here is my code:

```
let test = new CountUp('test', 1000000, { duration: 1000000, useEasing: false });
test.start();
```

I am trying to count to 1 million with an increment of 1 per second. To achieve that, I put the duration of 1 million seconds.

However, when I run the test, the increment is not happening at exactly 1 second. Is this by design? How can I achieve the exact 1 second?

Thanks

Comment: i don't think it's used for that.. looking at it carefully, you can see that it slow down as each number reaches it's goal.. eg: if my goal is 7777, it will go at a certain speed until 7000 then a slower speed(about 10 times slower) to 7700 and 100 times slower to 7770 then 1000 times slower to 7777.. **NOTE** im estimating and it could be a different slowing method, BUT it slows down as it gets closer to the goal

Comment: long and short of it, the rate of counting is not linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CountUp.js` is not linear by design, however it is not hard to have a basic counter of your own(nope I don't have a stop or start, but if you want I can make a class to imitate starting and stopping and other stuff)

This counter counts fully linear, takes in an element, seconds to count in, and a number to count to

```js
function CountUp(elem, secondsToCountIn, numberToCountTo){
  var n=0
  var i=setInterval(
    ()=>{
      if(n>numberToCountTo){return clearInterval(i)}
      elem.innerText=n
      n++
    },
    ((secondsToCountIn/numberToCountTo)*1000).toFixed()
  )
}

//example usage
CountUp(document.getElementById('y'),20,7000)
CountUp(document.getElementById('x'),1000,1000)
```

```html
<h1 id="y" style="color:lightblue"></h1>
<p id="x"></p>
```